# How to export views and import it in other DB?

Tags: mysql, export, dump, import

I am trying to export the database and everything is fine but I am not able to export the VIEWS.

Is it possible to export the views from sql queries and import it?

Comment: which toll have you used for backup? share your commands. mysqldump do give views as well in the backup. Do you have got any errors?

Comment: You might check out linux command line examples like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11109667) on the stack